# Rails 4, Sum value for nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I have nested attribute models like below,

```
Model Parent
has_many :students
has_many :classinos, through: :students
accepts_nested_attributes_for :students, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:firstname].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true

Model Student
belongs_to :Parents, for
has_many :classinfos, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :classlists, :through => :classinfos
accepts_nested_attributes_for :classinfos, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:classlist_id].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true

Model Classinfo
belongs_to :student, foreign_key: :student_id
belongs_to :classlist, foreign_key: :classlist_id

Model Classlist
has_many :students, :through => :classinfos
has_many :classinfos
```

---

The relationship is like...
Parent(calculate tuitions) << Student << Classinfo >> Classlist(:tuition)

Model Classlist has a column called "tuition", I want to sum up all the tuition for students and calculate in Parents model.

so far I have...

```
Model Classinfo
def tuitioncount
Classlist.where(:id => self.classlist_id).sum(:tuition)
end
```

I can show the tuitioncount for students by

```
<% @student.classinfos.order(classlist_id: :asc).each do |classinfo| %>
<%= classinfo.tuitioncount%>
<%end%>
```

but I dont know how to sum them up and def a method in Model Parent.
I need something like...

```
Model Parent
def balance
Classlist.where(:id => self.students.classinfos.classlist_id).sum(:tuition)
(or)
Student.where(:member_id => self.id).sum("student.tuitioncount")
end
```

Please help me, I don't really know how to extract values from a really far nested model...

Comment: One way is `Student.where(:member_id => self.id).to_a.sum { |student| student.tuitioncount }` .. But I think there can be made 1 query to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed your associations right, something like this.

```
class Parent
  has_many :students
  has_many :classinfos, through: :students
  has_many :classlists, through: :classinfos

  def balance
    self.classlists.sum(:tuition)
  end
end
```

Note: support for this style of deeply nested association was added in Rails 3.1, so earlier versions will need a different solution.